# Multi-site with two sites sharing the same domain?

Tags: 7, multi-sites

There is absolutely no problem to have multi sites, where:

- **domain1.com** points to site A
- **domain2.com** points to site B

But I want to have multi-site setup, where:

- **domain1.com** points to site A
- **domain1.com/blabla** points to site B

I was doing everything to solve it, for example using directory structure like that:

- domain1.com
- domain1.com.blabla

or using file sites.php with content:

```
$sites = array(
'domain1.com' => 'domain1.com',
'domain1.com' => 'domain1.com.blabla',
);
```

Nothing works, site 'domain1.com' takes all traffic.

FYI:

- I'm using nginx.
- I'm using Drupal 7.
- I do not want to use the module [Domain](https://www.drupal.org/project/domain) as I want to have separated databases.

Please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have done this before. Given a generic `location / { ... }` entry for Nginx which serves `domain1.com` to make the subdirectory install work I did the following 2 steps. I am not aware of a solution that doesn't involve making a symlink.

**Step 1:**

In your Nginx configuration:

```
    location / {
            # First attempt to serve request as file, then
            # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
            index index.php;
            try_files $uri $uri/ @rewrite;
            expires max;
            # Uncomment to enable naxsi on this location
            # include /etc/nginx/naxsi.rules
    }

    location /blabla {
     try_files $uri $uri/ /blabla/index.php?$args;
    }
    location ~ /blabla/.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|css|png|js|ico|xml)$ {
            webuser /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }
```

**Step 2:**

Then wherever your docroot is for your site you add an alias with your subfolder name to the main docroot, allowing the path to be valid for Drupal:

```
$ pwd
/usr/share/nginx/html

user@localhost:/usr/share/nginx/html$ find . -type l -ls
41059    0 lrwxrwxrwx   1 webuser    webuser           21 Sep 25 01:58 ./blabla -> /usr/share/nginx/html
```

You will still need your `sites.php` configuration as you have listed. You will need to restart Nginx.

Comment: `try_files $uri $uri/ /blabla/index.php?$args;` was crucial, it works fantastic! I was doing many combinations before, but it is a perfect solution, thanks a lot!

Comment: Is there any way to make it work without creating symlinks in the filesystem?

Comment: none that i'm aware of.